# Getting started with GUI programming with C or C++ on Mac

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, user-interface

I am on a mac using xcode and I have been programming in C and C++ for a while now, however, I have no idea how to go past the simple text input/output programs that I have been writing. I understand the principles, but taking it past the basics has proven difficult to figure out.

I hear libraries such as qt or gtk+ for C++ are the best way to go, but most books and tutorials focus on programming for windows or linux, and none show how these libraries work in the first place. I want to REALLY understand whats going on behind the scenes; I want to understand how GUIs work on the lowest level possible, even on the assembly and machine code level. Does anyone know where to get started with this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to make C/C++ apps for the Mac? Or other platforms? If only for the Mac, then it really would be beneficial to learn Objective-C. It really isn't the different from C. The hard part is learning all the APIs, but Apple has very good documentation.

Comment: I think I might do that for now, however if I eventually want to program for other Operating Systems what would you suggest?

Comment: Also, I would still like to understand it on a lower level.

Comment: It's OK to want to understand at a low level: But please use Qt, writing UIs at such level is not worth it.

Comment: Working at a low level will only confuse you if you are trying to understand how an UI framework works.  UI frameworks are universally high level.  It's kind of like asking how carpentry works at a molecular level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use OpenGL, you can get pretty low-level knowledge of how your graphics hardware does in order to produce the various UI elements that you want. Of course, you have to do all this work yourself. From designing the various UI items, to creating pixel buffers and texture mapping, and using a frame buffer. This part is also cross platform.

You also get to handle user interaction and interface logic yourself (polling the mouse/keyboard amongst other things). It might take you sometime to code up the more complex widgets, but at least you will get to do it all yourself which will give you quite a fair bit of insight into how GUI toolkits work.

GLUT comes with most Macs, and gives you the bare essentials for you to get started (you at least get a window :))

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/glut/Introduction/Intro.html

The GLUT library supports the following functionality:

1. Multiple windows for OpenGL rendering.
2. Callback driven event processing.
3. An `idle' routine and timers.
4. Utility routines to generate various solid and wire frame objects.
5. Support for bitmap and stroke fonts.
6. Miscellaneous window management functions.

http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php

Comment: Great answer, are there any good books or tutorials out there on OpenGL?

Comment: Ive updated my answer a little. Here are some resources:

1.[Xcode GLUT Tutorial](http://cit.cs.dixie.edu/cs/3600/xcode-glut/index.html)
2.[Basics of GLUT](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/basics-of-glut-r1680)
3.[GLUT Drawing](http://davidwparker.com/2011/08/20/opengl-screencast-6-drawing-in-3d-part-1-glut-objects/)

Note that Cocoa is actually optional for GLUT, you can create GUIs in plain C or C++.